# How to get the "rendered length" of Unicode string containing combining characters in PHP?

Tags: php, string, unicode, localization, internationalization

Considered that not all unicode combining characters have an equivalent precomposed one (NFC), is there a way to get the string's "rendered" length using PHP, if this is possible / makes semantically sense?

http://3v4l.org/L1kPl (using php7 escape syntax)

```
<?php
echo $s = "\u{0071}\u{0307}\u{0323}";
echo "\n";
echo mb_strlen(Normalizer::normalize($s, Normalizer::FORM_C), "UTF-8");
// Shows 3 because there is no precomposed equivalent
// for such glyph. I want to get 1 instead
```

What I achieved so far: http://3v4l.org/4NSCi

```
<?php
echo $s = "\u{0071}\u{0307}\u{0323}";
$r = Normalizer::normalize($s, Normalizer::FORM_C);
echo mb_strlen(preg_replace("@\p{Mn}@u", "", $r), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I think this is the first question I've seen for php7 - it might be worth creating a `php7` tag if it doesn't already exist

Comment: well that's not actually about php7, i've used the php7 unicode escape syntax just for convenience for the readers :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
grapheme_strlen()
```

It takes one argument that needs to be a valid utf-8 string.
Here's the reference: [Graphme cluster boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)